# How to make Spree promotional rule work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, solidus

I want to create a promotional-rule in the spree in which Free gift added to the cart for the first-time buyer. It means if anybody purchase from my shop as the first-time buyer he will get a specific product as a gift and it will be added to the checkout basket. I try to deploy it from promotion section of spree admin panel. But while I tried to test it as the first-time buyer it doesn't work. The gift item is not added to the cart. Please help me to activate the promotional rule.Thanks

[image]

Comment: i am not trying to add into stock. I am trying to add it into cart while checkout.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set the rule to only activate if the order already contains the Free Gift. Try eliminating that last condition ("Order includes specified product(s)") and seeing if that works.